# Why does overloaded assignment operator return reference to class?

Tags: c++

```
class item {
public:
    item& operator=(const item &rh) {
        ...
        ...
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Is the following signature wrong?

```
void operator=(const item &rh);
```

```
item a, b;
a = b; // equivalent to a.operator=(b); so there is no need to return this.
```

Answer (score 10):

It is not "wrong", but surprising. An assignment evaluates to the target object. That's what the builtin meaning is. If you define it different for your own class, people could become confused.

Example:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
  // ...
}
```

The assignment to `c` returned `c` itself and compared it to `EOF` afterwards. Users would expect your `item` class to behave similar.

Answer (score 6):

The signature with void would not allow chained assignments:

```
a = b = c;
```

(Look at Johannes' answer for one more example of a usage pattern based on assignment returning the assigned value.)

That's why using such signatures is discouraged. However, if I am not mistaken, you actually *can* use such a signature.

Comment: and crucially this is what built in types do

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly legal. But when you declare `operator=` like that, you will be unable to make "chain of assignment":

```
item a(X);
item b;
item c;
c = b = a;
```

Reference allows modifying returned value. Since `operator=` is evaluated from right to left, the usage I showed to you is working.

**EDIT** Also, as others mentioned, return value is often used in expressions like `while (a = cin.get()) != 'q')`. But you also can declare operator like `A operator=(const A&)` (returns copy) or `const A& operator(const A&)` (returns const reference). My point is: this operator can return *anything*, but the idiomatic way is to return non-const reference to itself.

Comment: Not only that, declaring `operator=` as returning `void` you won't be able to use the result of the assignment into any expression.