# Overloading assignment operator: if we return (*this), which is a value at a pointer/address, what's right syntax for assignment operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference, assignment-operator

Using these two previous threads as examples

First thread:
[Why does overloaded assignment operator return reference to class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360775/why-does-overloaded-assignment-operator-return-reference-to-class)

Second thread:
[Why must the copy assignment operator return a reference/const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference)

Is the return type of an overloaded assignment operator a class or a reference to a class?  I have seen both:

```
Point& Point::operator = (const Point& sourcePoint)
{
// As in the first thread I pasted above
return *this;
}
```

And

```
Point Point::operator = (const Point& sourcePoint)
{
// As in the second thread I pasted above
return *this;
}
```

Which is right?

Similarly, what's the difference between:

```
int exFunction()
{
     int i = 5;
     int* iPtr = &i;
     return *iPtr;
}
```

Versus:

```
int& exFunction2()
{
     int j = 5;
     int* jPtr = &j;
     return *jPtr;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The two thigns are not "similar" at all.

First off, the assignment operators. They should return a reference to the object itself, so that you can use them in a chain:

```
Foo x, y, z;

x = y = z;   // makes y equal to z and returns a reference to self,
             // which is assigned to x
```

So it's always:

```
Foo & operator=(Foo const &) { /* ... */  return this; }  // copy-assignment

Foo & operator=(/* any other signature */) { /* ... */   return this; }
```

Now, the second question: Your `exFunction2` is completely wrong and broken. It has undefined behaviour, because it returns a reference to a local variable, which is out of scope by the time the function returns. (It says essentially `return j;`; remember that the result of a dereference is an lvalue.) The only sensible way to write that function is like `exFunction`, which can be shortened to `int exFunction() { return 5; }`.

Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13077979/596781) on this topic.