# operator overloading passed and returned arguments

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I see that in a lot of examples in c++ that operator overloading gets as an argument a class instance passed by reference or if it returns a class instance it returns it by reference as well. Is there any reason why people choose to pass it by reference while passing a pointer / by value will work as well ?
An example :

```
Class MyClass
{
public:
    int m_num;
    MyClass() { m_num = 1;}
    const MyClass operator+(const MyClass& mcls)
    {
        MyClass temp;
        temp = m_num + mcls.m_num;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Assume that we overload the = operator.

So taking for example the code I wrote, sending arguments to the operator+ overload function NOT by reference AND ALSO returning an instance of MyClass not by reference will work as well yet I see in a lot of examples it's passed and returned by reference and I would like to know if there's a reason behind this or it's just convention of some type or maybe a preference ?

Comment: Returning a const reference there isn't really good at all. Check the warning you should have.

Comment: mind explaining what you're saying more in depth ? And also address my main question

Comment: @Tugal.44, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/824e82a5c9e1cf8c

Comment: @chris sorry I didn't notice I did that, tried to shove this into my example without really paying attention to what I was doing, fixed. So about my main question, you think you could answer that ? Why sometimes when you pass people choose to pass by ref most of the time

Comment: Well, returning a const value disables moving the return value from the function in the case RVO can't do anything for it. If it's C++11, you can suffer from putting the `const` there.

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360775/why-does-overloaded-assignment-operator-return-reference-to-class) for explanation of the return type

Comment: @MattMcNabb I see someone answered while((c = getchar()) != EOF) with this example, my brain can't process what's wrong with it if the =operator would return void, so c gets assigned and then being checked if it's != EOF

Comment: @Tugal44 `void` cannot be an operand of `!=`. It seems like you fundamentally don't understand how expressions work in C++.   Every expression results in a value.  When you have `(a + b) + c` for example, first the value is computed by `(a + b)`, and then the second step is that the result of that computation (which doesn't have a name) is added to `c`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb so the operators acts like functions returning a value ? and if it won't return a value you wouldn't be able to use a compound operator ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Ok I think I've got it, thanks for sticking here trying to explain this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, passing by reference or by constant reference is not required: the code would work with passing by value. However, for most operators that would be inefficient, because passing by value entails copying the entire object - something you avoid when you pass by reference.

Same goes for returning a value: more often than not, you should return by value. However, there is one notable exception to this rule: all compound assignment operators need to return by reference, because they return `(*this)`.

Using pointers instead of references is out of the question, but for a different reason: C++ requires operators to be compatible with specific signatures by type; a reference is type-compatible with a value of the corresponding type, but a pointer is incompatible. If you define an overload of an operator that takes pointers, C++ would not use your operators when working with values.

Comment: Regarding to your second assignment operator. Why should I return anything ? Won't returning void be good enough ? it's just assigning the values so why should I return *this ?

Comment: @Tugal.44 Because you can chain assignments and compound assignments, as in `a = b = c` or `a = b = c++` etc.

Comment: Why in chain assignments can't it act as if we were to write a = b = c so when doing b = c, b values changes and then a = b, a values changes, still don't understand how returning a ref is necessary ?

Comment: @Tugal.44, If `b = c` returns `void`, you've got `a = someVoidThing`. You can verify that yourself with a compiler.

Comment: @Tugal.44 If assignment or compound assignment returned by value, the semantics of this would be wrong: `MyClass a; MyClass b; MyClass &c = a = b;` In the above code, `c` is supposed to be a reference to `a` itself, not to its copy.

Comment: @chris but the way I would've implemented operator= would be something like m_num = mcls.m_num; I'm not returning just assigning so if I chaning a = b = c, b = c, b changes and then a = b, a changes (assuming that is the order) even if that's not the order then it'll still assign the values the other direction

Comment: @Tugal44 `a=b=c;` means `a = (b = c);` . You seem to be tacitly assuming it means `b = c; a = b;` but it doesn't.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so we return *this just in the case of when we could have a ref to an object ? but you said we should return *this in all compound assignments so what about operator+ ? it's compound yet there's no risk of what you just described as assigning ref to object values.

Comment: @MattMcNabb nonetheless I said what I think applies in any order, so if it goes from left to right then a = b = c, first a = b, a values will change then the other assignment

Comment: @Tugal44 You're making stuff up. `a = b = c;` means `a = (b = c);`, that's how C++ language is defined.

Comment: @Tugal.44 `+` is not compound, `+=` is. You can do this, too: `MyClass &c = a += b`, and `c` should become a reference to `a`. In general, you want to maintain semantics for your classes that matches semantics of built-in types.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if I can do for example c = a + b + d does it count as a compound operation ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb if a = b = c is a = (b = c) how isn't it like b = c; a = b; ? Can't see how, mind explaining ?

Comment: @Tugal44 because that is what the definition of C++ is .

Comment: @MattMcNabb so what a = b = c actually means ? Because if it doesn't mean b = c; a = b; I can't understand what it means

Comment: It means `a = (b = c);`. I don't know any way to say this more clearly. The result of `b = c` is the return value of the `operator=` function.

Comment: @Tugal.44, Here's an example of them obviously acting differently. Notice how one compiles and the other doesn't: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee3e0daa448f5522. `b = c` is an expression, just like `b` is, and just like `c` is, and just like `2+5` is. The result of that expression is used for the chaining: `a = (b = c)` becomes `a = result`. It just happens to have a side effect, which is updating `b`'s value.

Answer (score 1):

If your actual question is about passing by const reference, then see [Why pass by const reference instead of by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582797/why-pass-by-const-reference-instead-of-by-value), otherwise keep reading.

---

You shouldn't [return a reference to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable). The local variable goes out of scope, leaving a reference to garbage. The [C++ operator overloading guidelines](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html) state that `operator+` shouldn't modify either operands and returns a new value from the two arguments.

```
const MyClass operator+(const MyClass& mcls) const
{
    MyClass temp = *this;
    temp.m_num += mcls.m_num;
    return temp;
}
```

For this reason, it is important you return a copy.

On the other hand, regarding `operator=`, you do want to return a reference because it is the [copy assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator). For example:

```
  MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass &rhs) {
    // Check for self-assignment!
    if (this == &rhs)      // Same object?
      return *this;        // Yes, so skip assignment, and just return *this.

    ... // Deallocate, allocate new space, copy values...

    return *this;
  }
```

You want to copy `rhs` into `*this` and return a reference:

> [...] to support safe and reasonable operator chaining. (Do this by returning *this.)

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding why returning *this will allow chaining, dasblinkenlight explained the same thing to me and I've responded explaining what I don't understand, mind checking this ?

Answer (score 1):

If your function were:

```
MyClass operator+(const MyClass *mcls)
```

then the code `a + b` would not compile. You'd have to write `a + &b` which is horrible.

It is valid to have the operator as:

```
MyClass operator+(MyClass mcls)
```

This code , conceptually, creates an extra copy of `mcls` because it is passed by value. If this copy can actually be moved out of, or elided or otherwize optimized out, then this is a good style. Otherwise, the `const MyClass &` version is a good optimization (sometimes a premature one!) to avoid this potential extra copy.

Note that both of these should be `const` (that is, the function - not the return value) since they do not modify `*this`. And it is considered better style for `operator+` to be a non-member function

The reason that `operator+` should not return a reference is that people expect that `+` takes two inputs and generates a new output.  If the code is `c = a + b;` then we expect `a` to remain unchanged. You have to make a new object somewhere which holds the sum, and return that. When we return by value, this is a temporary object and usually the compiler will elide it and write the results directly into `c`.

It is correct for `operator+=` to modify `*this` and return a reference to `*this`. A good way of implementing `operator+` is actually to just call `operator+=` on the first operand (when passed by value).

Comment: Why is it considered a better style for operator+ to be a non-member function ? I agree on making them const, forgot. Also why operator+= should return *this ? What's wrong with just modifying this members and be done with it, why the need of returning from += operator ?

Comment: If it is a non-member than you can write both `c = 3 + b;` and `c = a + 3;`  if your class has any converting constructors from `int`.  Also it's better for code modularity and encapsulation to separate your object's functionality from operations which are done on your object.

Comment: You could return `void` in `operator+=` but you may as well return `*this` to allow chaining, e.g. `func( a += b );` which means `a += b; func(a);`.  The general idea in designing your overloaded operators is to make them behave as closely as possible to how the built-in operators behave for built-in types. Then people who use your operator do not have any unpleasant surprises in store for them.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding why returning *this will allow chaining, dasblinkenlight explained the same thing to me and I've responded explaining what I don't understand, mind checking this ?

Comment: @Tugal44 your question is really asking two separate questions: (a) why pass parameters by const reference, (b) why does operator+ return by value. You should have posted two separate questions (or consulted existing answers, probably there is already a question for each of those). If you want to include operator+= as well then that's another question. This should all be explained by whatever book or guide you are using to learn operator overloading.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't explain it (for now, maybe it'll later) and I'm just asking about the operators return type because you guys decided to point me this as something I should note of